# need a better way to map database field names

Tags: php

I am working on a project where we are exporting tables fields as XML files for different customers
where Table's column name will be used as node name in XML file.

But almost every customer wants to have a user friendly node name. So we have to map Table's column names with Desired node names using Associative Arrays.

like

```
['fieldName 1'] = 'NodeName1'
['fieldName 2'] = 'NodeName2'
['fieldName 3'] = 'NodeName3'
....
....
['fieldName n'] = 'NodeNameN'
```

Is there any other/better idea to map them?

Thank you

Comment: Can you not store both?

Comment: This is kind of an associative array's bread and butter use. You could store it in a fancy translate function or separate language class but you will still need an array somewhere to map from and to.

Comment: Well, you've got to do the mapping somewhere. The only other approach I can think of that might be sensible is to use an XSLT transform on the resulting output files per customer. So every file would be output in the same way, but then before it was sent to the customer you'd run a simple XSL transform on it (a different file, or a different mapping file as input, per customer) that would change the names. That would be simple to do and very easy to update, but I'd only go down that road if you're already relatively familiar with XSLT.

Comment: @Matt: XSLT would have been my *starting* point - not last resort. Surely that's the point of XML in the first place!

Comment: @symcbean Where did I say it would be my last resort? I'd start there, too, but I can see why someone who's asking a PHP question about some existing PHP code might want to use a PHP solution if they don't already know the basics... XSLT, like most things, is one of those "simple if you know how" options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have readable column names (like `my_column_name`) than you can convert it to friendly name like `My column name`

```
ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $columnName));
```

If you need specific names (like `my_column_name` must be `Column of mine to use in categories`) than you will need array map for that:

```
$map = [
    'my_column_name' => 'Column name of something',
    ...
];
```